# Interdependent color swatch widgets

Tags: javascript, css, html5, angular.js, graphics

To illustrate some algorithmic problems I found while writing [this code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/71399/9357), I needed to include a live demonstration, which I implemented using a Stack Snippet with Angular.js.

The demonstration takes a color input and a scalar parameter, and produces two read-only color outputs.  The "Original" output is known to behave erratically (which is the point of the demo).

However, the HTML feels a bit repetitive. How can I use Angular more effectively? Optional bonus question: would your advice change if I wanted to present one of the outputs as HSV values instead of RGB?

I also think that the CSS is sloppy and not robust to various sizing conditions.  Recommendations in that area would also be appreciated.

(For this review, I suggest treating the details of the color manipulation routines as black boxes. For those issues, you may comment on the original answer instead.)

```js
var ColorTweakerCtrl = function ColorTweakerCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.inColor  = new RGBColor(234, 150, 0);
  $scope.diff = 127;
  
  $scope.tweak = function tweak() {
    $scope.inColor.r = Math.round($scope.inColor.r);
    $scope.inColor.g = Math.round($scope.inColor.g);
    $scope.inColor.b = Math.round($scope.inColor.b);
    $scope.diff = Math.round($scope.diff);
    $scope.outColor = tweakColor($scope.inColor, $scope.diff);
    $scope.newColor = newTweakColor($scope.inColor, $scope.diff);
  };
  $scope.tweak();
};


function RGBColor(r, g, b) {
  this.r = r; this.g = g; this.b = b;
}

RGBColor.prototype.toString = function() {
  return 'rgb(' + Math.round(this.r) + ',' + Math.round(this.g) + ',' + Math.round(this.b) + ')';
};

/* Based on formulas from http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.htm */
RGBColor.prototype.toHSV = function toHSV() {
  var r = this.r / 255,
      g = this.g / 255,
      b = this.b / 255;
  var cMax = Math.max(r, g, b),
      cMin = Math.min(r, g, b);
  var Δ = cMax - cMin;
  var hue = 60 * ( (cMax == r) ? ((g - b) / Δ) % 6
                 : (cMax == g) ? ((b - r) / Δ) + 2
                               : ((r - g) / Δ) + 4 );
  var sat = cMax == 0 ? 0 : Δ / cMax;
  var val = cMax;
  return new HSVColor((hue + 360) % 360, sat, val);
}

function HSVColor(h, s, v) {
  this.h = h; this.s = s; this.v = v;
}

HSVColor.prototype.toString = function() {
  return 'hsl(' + Math.round(this.h) + ',' + Math.round(100 * this.s) + '%,' + Math.round(100 * this.v) + '%)';
};

/* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSV */
HSVColor.prototype.toRGB = function toRGB() {
  var c = this.v * this.s;
  var h = this.h / 60;
  var x = c * (1 - Math.abs(h % 2 - 1));
  var r1 = (h < 1 || h >= 5) ? c
         : (h < 2 || h >= 4) ? x : 0;
  var g1 = (h >= 1 && h < 3) ? c
         : (h >= 0 && h < 4) ? x : 0;
  var b1 = (h >= 3 && h < 5) ? c
         : (h >= 2 && h < 6) ? x : 0;
  var m = this.v - c;
  return new RGBColor(Math.round(255 * (r1 + m)),
                      Math.round(255 * (g1 + m)),
                      Math.round(255 * (b1 + m)));
};


function tweakColor(aColor, aDiff) {
  function intRange(value, min, max) {
    return value < min ? min
         : value > max ? max
                       : value;
  }
  var r = aColor.r,
      g = aColor.g,
      b = aColor.b;
  var d = (r + g + b) / 3;
  var dir = (d >= (256 / 2)) ? -aDiff : aDiff;
  r = intRange(r + dir, 0, 255);
  g = intRange(g + dir, 0, 255);
  b = intRange(b + dir, 0, 255);
  return new RGBColor(r, g, b);
}

function newTweakColor(aColor, aDiff) {
  var hsv = aColor.toHSV();
  var vAdj = (aDiff / 128) * (hsv.v - 0.5);
  return (new HSVColor(hsv.h, hsv.s, hsv.v - vAdj)).toRGB();
}
```

```css
fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
fieldset#tweak {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-width: 0;
}
label {
  display: block;
}
.swatch {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
}
input[type=range] {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <form ng-controller="ColorTweakerCtrl">
    <fieldset id="tweak">
      <label>Diff
        <input ng-model="diff" type="range" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()">
        <input ng-model="diff" type="number" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()">
      </label>
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Input Color</legend>
      <div class="swatch" style="background-color: {{ inColor.toString() }}"></div>
      <label>R
        <input ng-model="inColor.r" type="range" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()">
        <input ng-model="inColor.r" type="number" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()">
      </label>
      <label>G
        <input ng-model="inColor.g" type="range" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()">
        <input ng-model="inColor.g" type="number" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()">
      </label>
      <label>B
        <input ng-model="inColor.b" type="range" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()">
        <input ng-model="inColor.b" type="number" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()">
      </label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Output (Original)</legend>
      <div class="swatch" style="background-color: {{ outColor.toString() }}"></div>
      <label>R
        <input ng-model="outColor.r" type="range" min="0" max="255" disabled>
        <input ng-model="outColor.r" type="number" min="0" max="255" disabled>
      </label>
      <label>G
        <input ng-model="outColor.g" type="range" min="0" max="255" disabled>
        <input ng-model="outColor.g" type="number" min="0" max="255" disabled>
      </label>
      <label>B
        <input ng-model="outColor.b" type="range" min="0" max="255" disabled>
        <input ng-model="outColor.b" type="number" min="0" max="255" disabled>
      </label>
    </fieldset>


    <fieldset>
      <legend>Output (Suggested)</legend>
      <div class="swatch" style="background-color: {{ newColor.toString() }}"></div>
      <label>R
        <input ng-model="newColor.r" type="range" min="0" max="255" disabled>
        <input ng-model="newColor.r" type="number" min="0" max="255" disabled>
      </label>
      <label>G
        <input ng-model="newColor.g" type="range" min="0" max="255" disabled>
        <input ng-model="newColor.g" type="number" min="0" max="255" disabled>
      </label>
      <label>B
        <input ng-model="newColor.b" type="range" min="0" max="255" disabled>
        <input ng-model="newColor.b" type="number" min="0" max="255" disabled>
      </label>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Markup

Your markup is invalid.  A label is only allowed to be associated with a single form element.

A color input element would be a more semantically appropriate choice over that div.

## CSS

For the RGB label text, I recommend switching to a mono-spaced font.  As it stands, your form elements will not line up because each letter varies in width.

I don't see much reason for your number fields to be any wider than what's necessary for the the widest number value visible (which might not be the highest number!).  A width of 3em-4em would probably be a good starting point.

Comment: Unfortunately, support for `<input type="color">` is currently [limited to Firefox, Chrome, and Opera](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color). Also, there is no telling what that widget would look like or how it would behave, as the spec is fuzzy.

Comment: There's no guarantees as to how *any* form element will look (notably, checkbox and file vary depending on browser/os).  An element should be chosen should be based on its purpose, not because of how it looks.  As a user, I only care how a particular element looks on *my* browser, how it looks on other browsers (whether it be the same or different) is of no concern to me.

Comment: A palette of 8 fixed color choices would be within the spec for `<input type="color">`. Furthermore, the fallback on browsers that don't support it yet is a text field.

Comment: what do you mean by `A label is only allowed to be associated with a single form element` I only see a single form element.

Comment: @Malachi I guess I should have said form controls, not form element.  Error from the validator: "label element with multiple labelable descendants" and "The label element may contain at most one input, button, select, textarea, or keygen descendant."

Comment: that looks like it should be a table...

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code from Labels to Tables I think

That way the Syntax is happy and everything still operates the same way.

something like this

```js
var ColorTweakerCtrl = function ColorTweakerCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.inColor  = new RGBColor(234, 150, 0);
  $scope.diff = 127;
  
  $scope.tweak = function tweak() {
    $scope.inColor.r = Math.round($scope.inColor.r);
    $scope.inColor.g = Math.round($scope.inColor.g);
    $scope.inColor.b = Math.round($scope.inColor.b);
    $scope.diff = Math.round($scope.diff);
    $scope.outColor = tweakColor($scope.inColor, $scope.diff);
    $scope.newColor = newTweakColor($scope.inColor, $scope.diff);
  };
  $scope.tweak();
};


function RGBColor(r, g, b) {
  this.r = r; this.g = g; this.b = b;
}

RGBColor.prototype.toString = function() {
  return 'rgb(' + Math.round(this.r) + ',' + Math.round(this.g) + ',' + Math.round(this.b) + ')';
};

/* Based on formulas from http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.htm */
RGBColor.prototype.toHSV = function toHSV() {
  var r = this.r / 255,
      g = this.g / 255,
      b = this.b / 255;
  var cMax = Math.max(r, g, b),
      cMin = Math.min(r, g, b);
  var Δ = cMax - cMin;
  var hue = 60 * ( (cMax == r) ? ((g - b) / Δ) % 6
                 : (cMax == g) ? ((b - r) / Δ) + 2
                               : ((r - g) / Δ) + 4 );
  var sat = cMax == 0 ? 0 : Δ / cMax;
  var val = cMax;
  return new HSVColor((hue + 360) % 360, sat, val);
}

function HSVColor(h, s, v) {
  this.h = h; this.s = s; this.v = v;
}

HSVColor.prototype.toString = function() {
  return 'hsl(' + Math.round(this.h) + ',' + Math.round(100 * this.s) + '%,' + Math.round(100 * this.v) + '%)';
};

/* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSV */
HSVColor.prototype.toRGB = function toRGB() {
  var c = this.v * this.s;
  var h = this.h / 60;
  var x = c * (1 - Math.abs(h % 2 - 1));
  var r1 = (h < 1 || h >= 5) ? c
         : (h < 2 || h >= 4) ? x : 0;
  var g1 = (h >= 1 && h < 3) ? c
         : (h >= 0 && h < 4) ? x : 0;
  var b1 = (h >= 3 && h < 5) ? c
         : (h >= 2 && h < 6) ? x : 0;
  var m = this.v - c;
  return new RGBColor(Math.round(255 * (r1 + m)),
                      Math.round(255 * (g1 + m)),
                      Math.round(255 * (b1 + m)));
};


function tweakColor(aColor, aDiff) {
  function intRange(value, min, max) {
    return value < min ? min
         : value > max ? max
                       : value;
  }
  var r = aColor.r,
      g = aColor.g,
      b = aColor.b;
  var d = (r + g + b) / 3;
  var dir = (d >= (256 / 2)) ? -aDiff : aDiff;
  r = intRange(r + dir, 0, 255);
  g = intRange(g + dir, 0, 255);
  b = intRange(b + dir, 0, 255);
  return new RGBColor(r, g, b);
}

function newTweakColor(aColor, aDiff) {
  var hsv = aColor.toHSV();
  var vAdj = (aDiff / 128) * (hsv.v - 0.5);
  return (new HSVColor(hsv.h, hsv.s, hsv.v - vAdj)).toRGB();
}
```

```css
fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
fieldset#tweak {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-width: 0;
}
label {
  display: block;
}
.swatch {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
}
input[type=range] {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <form ng-controller="ColorTweakerCtrl">
    <fieldset id="tweak">
      <label>Diff
        <input ng-model="diff" type="range" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()">
        <input ng-model="diff" type="number" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()">
      </label>
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Input Color</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <div class="swatch" style="background-color: {{ inColor.toString() }}"></div>
                <td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> R </td>
                <td> 
                    <input ng-model="inColor.r" type="range" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-model="inColor.r" type="number" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()" />
                </td>
            <tr>
            <tr>
                <td> G </td>
                <td> 
                    <input ng-model="inColor.g" type="range" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-model="inColor.g" type="number" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()" />
                </td>
            <tr>
            <tr>
                <td> B </td>
                <td> 
                    <input ng-model="inColor.b" type="range" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-model="inColor.b" type="number" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()" />
                </td>
            <tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Output (Original)</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <div class="swatch" style="background-color: {{ outColor.toString() }}"></div>
                <td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> R </td>
                <td> 
                    <input ng-model="outColor.r" type="range" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-model="outColor.r" type="number" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()" />
                </td>
            <tr>
            <tr>
                <td> G </td>
                <td> 
                    <input ng-model="outColor.g" type="range" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-model="outColor.g" type="number" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()" />
                </td>
            <tr>
            <tr>
                <td> B </td>
                <td> 
                    <input ng-model="outColor.b" type="range" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-model="outColor.b" type="number" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()" />
                </td>
            <tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Output (Suggested)</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <div class="swatch" style="background-color: {{ newColor.toString() }}"></div>
                <td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> R </td>
                <td> 
                    <input ng-model="newColor.r" type="range" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-model="newColor.r" type="number" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()" />
                </td>
            <tr>
            <tr>
                <td> G </td>
                <td> 
                    <input ng-model="newColor.g" type="range" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-model="newColor.g" type="number" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()" />
                </td>
            <tr>
            <tr>
                <td> B </td>
                <td> 
                    <input ng-model="newColor.b" type="range" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-model="newColor.b" type="number" min="0" max="255" ng-change="tweak()" />
                </td>
            <tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The `width: 40%` rule now means 40% of the width of the cell rather than 40% of the width of the `fieldset`, which is why the slider is now too short.

Comment: that makes sense...lol. if I remove that they get too wide, I will leave as is but take out the comment, it still functions but needs to be tweaked a little bit.